Counter value is not decreasing while using multithreaded loop
I am working on a multi-threaded application using Task.WhenAll() to process multiple requests concurrently. However, I’m encountering unexpected behavior where shared data is being corrupted, possibly due to a race condition.
Here’s the code:
public class DataProcessor
{
    private static int _counter = 0;

    public async Task ProcessDataAsync()
    {
        var tasks = new List<Task>();

        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
        {
            tasks.Add(Task.Run(() => IncrementCounter()));
        }

        await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
    }

    private void IncrementCounter()
    {
        _counter++;
    }
}

After running this code, the value of _counter is often less than 1000, indicating that some increments might be missed. How can I fix this issue and ensure thread-safe operations in this multi-threaded context?
I have no idea for it now

Post-increment is indeed not thread safe, you'd have to use something like Interlocked.Increment(ref _counter); or lock (_counter) { _counter++; }. See C# Thread safe fast(est) counter

The issue here is that _counter++ is not thread-safe. It seems like a simple increment operation, but in reality, it involves three steps:

Read the value of _counter.
Increment the value.
Write the updated value back to _counter.

In a multi-threaded environment, multiple threads can read and increment _counter simultaneously, leading to missed updates and race conditions. This is why the final value of _counter is often less than expected.
Use Interlocked for Atomic Operations: The Interlocked class provides atomic operations for variables that are shared across threads.
Interlocked.Increment ensures that the increment operation is atomic and thread-safe. It avoids race conditions without needing explicit locks.
Interlocked Class API - Microsoft
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

public class DataProcessor
{
    // Shared counter, incremented atomically
    private static int _counter = 0;

    public async Task ProcessDataAsync()
    {
        const int taskCount = 1000;
        var tasks = new List<Task>(taskCount);

        // Add tasks to increment the counter
        for (int i = 0; i < taskCount; i++)
        {
            tasks.Add(Task.Run(IncrementCounter));
        }

        // Wait for all tasks to complete
        await Task.WhenAll(tasks);

        Console.WriteLine($"Final Counter Value: {_counter}");
    }

    private void IncrementCounter()
    {
        Interlocked.Increment(ref _counter); // Atomic increment
    }

    // Entry point to test the code
    public static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        var processor = new DataProcessor();
        await processor.ProcessDataAsync();
    }
}


If you need more complex operations on shared data, you can use a lock to ensure that only one thread at a time can access _counter.

thanks @Alander , It helps me to understand and resole the issue
